# How to execute J2ME polish app in nokia sdk 1.1 emulator

Tags: java-me, nokia, j2mepolish, polish

I was trying to execute a J2Me Polish app with the emulator that came with my nokia sdk 1.1 and got this error message

> C:\Users\Jade\J2ME-Polish2.3\Projects\FirstHello\nbproject\build-impl.xml:782: Execution failed with error code 1.

and on line 782 of build-impl.xml i have this:

```
     <nb-run jadfile="${dist.dir}/${dist.jad}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${dist.jar}" jadurl="${dist.jad.url}" device="${platform.device}" platformhome="${platform.home}" platformtype="${platform.type}" execmethod="${run.method}" securitydomain="${evaluated.run.security.domain}" commandline="${platform.runcommandline}" classpath="${platform.bootclasspath}:${dist.dir}/${dist.jar}" cmdoptions="${run.cmd.options}"/>
```

can anyone help?

Comment: There is not much information to work with on the error message, perhaps you can add echo lines to build-impl.xml to see the values for those variables

Comment: Have you installed emulator of Nokia 1.1 and have you added that emulator in platforms ?